# How to create adjustable UIView similar to the Pic Jointer / Diptic apps in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I am working on app like on [Pic Jointer](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/pic-jointer/id509987785?mt=8) / [Diptic](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/diptic/id377989827?mt=8). I am successfully able to create two separate view which are re-sizable separately, but I want to implement an adjustable view like the [Pic Jointer](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/pic-jointer/id509987785?mt=8) and [Diptic](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/diptic/id377989827?mt=8) apps.

I have tried lot to make a UIView similar to some example apps, however I've failed to implement this kind functionality. I have also successfully been able to create two separate UIViews which can be resized and dragged.

Can any one guide me how can I achieve this kind of functionality? Tutorials, links, explanations, open source libraries, anything?

What kind of functionality would this require, and how would one go about implementing that using UIImageView and / or UIView?

Comment: I have also waiting for the same!!! Please Help..

Comment: In order to get useful answers, you need to show what you've done and where you're stuck. No one will write a whole program for you, but we're happy to help with specific steps and nudges in the right direction.

Comment: @Dustin: i think i have provided sufficient info about my question. Ans for what i have done is "i am successfully able to create two separate view which are re-sizable separately." and where i stuck is "if you have seen screenshot of this apps you will be able to understand i want to create adjustable view in which frames are adjustable". i am not looking for a program. i need guidance how can i achieve this kind of functionality.

Comment: I have edited the question, and it would be nice if we could have a vote to reopen.

Comment: @Wolverine Have you Achieve this? I want to do the Same. Please Help.!